# PHP - building query for table filters

Tags: php, jquery, pdo

I need help with building a query, I have a form ( multiple dropdowns) and need to display a data table according to the user selection.

**filters.php** (on server side - ajax )

```
 $criteria[0] = $_POST['Size'];
 $criteria[1] = $_POST['Name'];
 $criteria[2] = $_POST['Color'];
 $criteria[3] = $_POST['Sku'];
 $criteria[4] = $_POST['Features'];

$statement = $dbh->prepare("select * from table_name where Sku = :sku AND Size = :size AND Color = :color AND Features LIKE :features ");

$statement->execute(array(':name' => $criteria[1], ':Size'=> $criteria[0], ':color'=>$criteria[2], ':sku'=>$criteria[3], ':features'=> '%'.$features[4].'%'));

$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$subrows = $statement->fetchAll();
// ect..
```

When all the criteria are selected ( all dropdowns have a value ) the call will return data , but what if the user only selects one, two or three dropdowns? It will return an empty table which is logic if using the query above.

I was thinking maybe I should try first to check if the variables are set, then perform for each scenario a query ? Im kind of lost how to implement it.

The idea is to have a small div with dropdowns next to the data table which allows filtering.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`If` statements dependent on the $_POST key may be the best way - and add the corresponding part to the query string:

i.e. :

```
 $queryString = "select * from table_name where ";
    if($_POST['SKU']){
         $queryString .= "Sku = :sku";
    }
```

Furthermore, to handle the "AND" parts :

```
$and = (count($_POST) > 1 ? 1 : 0);
```

and inside each `if` statement, the first line should be:

```
$queryString .= ($and ? "AND " : "");
```

Furthermore, I would suggest using an ORM, (Idiorm being my personal favorite, which I use in this example: )

```
$queryBuilder = ORM::for_table("table"); 

if($_POST['Sku']) 
     $queryBuilder = $queryBuilder->where("Sku", $_POST['Sku']);
```

and so on and so forth.

Comment: Thanks works great, I need to mention also add If condition for the PDO biding statements otherwise the query will not work. eg: if ($criteria[2]) {$statement->bindParam(':color', $Ids[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);}

Answer (score 0):

Check the desired variables to see if they contain data, if so you have to build the query. You can add to the array at the same time! For example:

```
$myarray = array();
if(!empty($criteria[0])){
$myarray["Size"] = $criteria[0];
}
```